# input type=image width being ignored

Tags: html, image

im making an image button like this:

```
<input type="image" src="red.jpeg" width="150px">
```

but it is displaying the original image size which is much larger, if i put:

```
<img src="red.jpeg" width="150px">
```

it displays the image 150px wide as i want,

what do you guys think is the problem with this? I have tried styling it with a class and CSS but not working either, please help me with this, im going nuts!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="image" src="red.jpeg" style="width:150px;" />
```

Comment: wow that actually worked, thanks !!! but, why does inline css works and when i styled it with a class applying a width didnt worked? do you know?

Comment: @kastulo not sure you have to see your CSS. My guess is your not using the first CSS selector/class. You can debug what styles/CSS is being applied using tools like firebug or IE dev tools

Answer (score 5):

The unit "px" is NOT valid inside a `width` attribute, since units like px, pt, ex ,em are a CSS syntax, but this attribute is not related to CSS:  It takes a unitless number or a percentage ONLY.  Try either using simply `width="150"`, or else use CSS via `style="width:150px"`.

Also, use of the `width` attribute on `<input type="image">` tags (specifically) seems to be new in HTML5 - it isn't in the HTML4.01 spec that I can see. (see [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), or compare [HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#the-input-element) at the W3C).  So older browsers may not recognize the `width` attribute as you've tried to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Styling can be done with either inline css or with a rule applied to the input element.
What doesn't work, is setting the width attribute of the input element - this is separate and distinct to the width attribute of the element's style.

Each of these two give an identical output:

1) Inline CSS

```
<input type="image" src="img/girl.png" style="width: 300px">
```

2) Non-inline css

```
.imgBtn
{
    width: 300px;
}

<input class='imgBtn' type="image" src="img/girl.png">
```

Comment: thanks!!, actually i did try to do it the non-inline way with a class selector but didnt work, still keep wondering why, but good think i have it working now..

Comment: You're welcome. They're (different methods) all just extra 'feathers in the cap'. :)

Comment: Also, when using the width ATTRIBUTE, you only ever use a number... no 'px'.  (e.g. on img tags).

Comment: @Doin - pardon? I _always_ use units. Failing to do so gives different results. E.g take the example (1) above. Try using each of these 3 next to each other - the images are all different sizes (specifying no units, as you suggest results in NO scaling)  (1) width:300px (2)width:300 (3)width:20em  - the last is nearly as large as the first!

Comment: Oops... I think my comment went to the wrong answer.  Units are for CSS only.  `<input width="...">` and `<input style="width:...">` have *different* syntax - and you can use units only in the latter case.  The OP has a `width="150px"` attribute on his input tag, which is a syntax error.  The browser will ignore it!

Comment: @Doin - ahh! That makes sense. You response has had me somewhat perplexed.. Thanks for the clarification. :)